# Firebase load all data from uid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have a big list of items where the user can go and favourite items as they wish. These favourites then go to a new node `userLikedItems/userUID/`.

When saving favourites, I am trying to figure out the best way to do so:

Here is my current, duplicative approach:

```
    //duplicating all the data when a user favourites an item into their own node under userLikedItems
    {
      "hwUjzftGyCgMrRgNv4Djg5F4ZCQ2" : {
        "24K Carrot" : {
          "effects" : {
            "Euphoria" : true,
            "Happy" : true,
            "Relaxing" : true,
            "Sleepy" : true
          },
          "medical" : {
            "Arthritis" : true,
            "Bipolar Disorder" : true,
            "Chronic Pain" : true,
            "Depression" : true,
            "Fatigue" : true,
            "Inflammation" : true,
            "Insomnia" : true,
            "Loss of Appetite" : true,
            "Migraines" : true,
            "PTSD" : true,
            "Stress" : true
          },
          "levels" : "18% - 24%",
          "title" : "24K Carrot",
          "titleLowercase" : "24k Carrot",
          "uid" : "24K Carrot"
        },
        "2 Pac" : {
          "effects" : {
            "Cerebral" : true,
            "Focus" : true,
            "Happy" : true,
            "Horny" : true,
            "Relaxing" : true,
            "Uplifting" : true
          },
          "medical" : {
            "Arthritis" : true,
            "Cramps" : true,
            "Depression" : true,
            "Gastrointestinal Disorder" : true,
            "Loss of Appetite" : true,
            "Migraines" : true
          },
          "levels" : "29%",
          "title" : "2 Pac",
          "titleLowercase" : "2 pac",
          "uid" : "2 Pac"
        },
      }
    }
```

Here is the next approach where I am trying to determine if it is a better practice than my current approach:

```
   //data stored with only uid:true under user's favourites node
   {
      "hwUjzftGyCgMrRgNv4Djg5F4ZCQ2" : {
        "24K Carrot" : true,
        "2 Pac" : true,
        "Triple Take" : true,
    }

      // fetching the rest of the data inside list item
      componentDidMount() {
          firebase.database().ref('/userLikedItems').child(this.props.user.item.uid).once('value', snapshot => {
            const itemData = snapshot.val();
            this.setState({
              name: itemData.name,
              image: itemData.image,
              type: itemData.type
            });
        });
      }
```

So basically when a list item is mounted I am calling this query to fetch the rest of the data. I am worried this is a bad practice.

Right now I am currently duplicating all the item data in the userLikedItems node which means I would not have to perform that query for every item, instead I would simply load all the data from the users node - the problem with this is I have to use a cloud function to keep the data consistent when the main item changes and there is a lot of duplicate data in my database when it could instead just be a simple boolean for each item.

I appreciate all the feedback!

Cheers.

Comment: The questions you ask are quite opinionated now. Things like "best" and "bad approach" are not objective, so will lead to opinions rather than facts. If you have a data model that works, but that doesn't perform in the way you expect in a certain use-case, it's best to ask about that.

Comment: Also keep in mind: you're asking us about a data model that we can't see. I highly recommend adding the JSON that you're talking about to your question (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Puf, I have updated my question.

Comment: OK.That helps in understanding your data model. But what is your question now, keeping in mind that "best" or "good" are often subjective (especially in NoSQL databases, where the data model often depends on your use-cases). If you're new to NoSQL data modeling, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated my question again, I basically am looking for feedback about the two approaches to saving user's favourites. One method I am saving the whole item node, the second approach would only save the uid with a boolean of true, then load the data for that node when the user needs it (on the details page when pressing list item)

Comment: Both are valid approaches. There is no singular "this is the right way" when it comes to NoSQL data modeling, as it depends on the use-cases of your app, what style you prefer, whether you care about storage size over bandwidth consumption, etc.